# Weird Date formats part of column in YY-mm-dd and the rest of columns YY-dd-mm

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is a strange one but I have an original excel with 10/11/2018 and the above problem happens when i convert column to datetime using:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

So the date column is 2018-01-11, then the date/months are equal for example 2018-11-11, it swaps the format of previous row and the row is now

```
 ''2018-11-12''
 ''2018-11-13''
```

ive tried to write a for loop for each entry changing the series but get error cant change series, then i tried writing a loop but get the time error

```
for date_ in jda.Date:
    jda.Date[date_] = jda.Date[date_].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

KeyError: Timestamp('2019-05-17 00:00:00')
```

Beow is a pic of where the forat changes 
Thank you for your help

[image: dateformat change]

Comment: Excel Dates have *no* format. The internal representation is a decimal (OADate). How they appear in the application depends on the cell's style. Pandas should have read those values as dates to begin with. If, on the other hand, an Evil User stored *strings* instead of dates you have no way of knowing what the format is. Excel would convert localized dates to OADate values automatically, which means the user used a *different* format that you now have to essentially guess

Comment: How do the dates look in the Excel file itself? Could it be that some rows have dates but some have *text* ? Can you inspect the rows around the point where the change happens, especially the styles? If you click on the cells themselves, what value do you see in the edit box? Does it start with a tick perhaps? That means the user forced it to text. Excel itself will display a green triangle at the top left corner of any field that contains text when the style is a number or date

Comment: Hi Panagiotis - all the excel rows are consistent - how do i know if a user stores them as strings? if by this u mean they are in quotes - no they are not

Comment: you may want to pass `dayfirst=True` to `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Hi there thanks all  i tried that but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if dates are saved like strings:

I think problem is wrong parsed datetimes, because by default are `10/11/2018` parsed to `11.October 2018`, so if need parse to `10. November 2018` format add `dayfirst=True` parameter in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or you can specify format e.g. `%d/%m/%Y` for `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Excel dates are stored as decimals, not strings. Pandas should have loaded those values as dates

Comment: many thanks @ jezraell , it wasnt string. Thanks all -  a conundrum. I avoided the problem by writing an if statement to take both formats as input